# Leading order of integrals in Field Theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, integration, asymptotics

I am studying Statistical Field Theory from the notes of D. Tong (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html). I have trouble to understand how to estimate the leading order of diverging integrals such as the one of Eq. (2.13):

\begin{equation}
  \int_0^{\Lambda}dk\frac{k^{d-1}}{\gamma k^2+\mu^2}\sim \begin{cases}
  \Lambda^{d-2}\quad\text{when } d>2 \newline
 \ln\Lambda \quad\text{when } d=2 \newline
  1/\mu\quad\text{when }d=1
 \end{cases}\,,\tag{2.13}
\end{equation}
where $\Lambda$ is the UV cutoff, $\gamma$ can be considered a constant, $\mu^2$ is basically $T-T_c$, the distance (in temperature) from the critical point and $d$ is the dimension of the space we are considering. Tong says "we can easily determine the leading order temperature dependence of the integral by rescaling variables". Can anyone justify this result?

Comment: In [“Statistical Field Theory”](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft/sft.pdf) - David Tong, equation 2.13 reads as Giancarlo Creanza’s original post.

Comment: For large $k$ one can write $\gamma k^{2} + \mu^{2} \approx \gamma k^{2} $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are large-$\Lambda$ results evaluable with $k=\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\gamma}}x$. If $d=1$ the integral converges to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\gamma}\,\mu}$ as $\Lambda\to\infty$. If $d\ge2$, the integral is divergent as $\Lambda\to\infty$, but we obtain an asymptotic behaviour in terms of finite $\Lambda\gg\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\gamma}}$. The case $d=2$ is special:$$\frac{1}{\gamma}\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\gamma}\,\Lambda}{\mu}\frac{xdx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\ln(1+\gamma\Lambda^2/\mu^2)}{2\gamma}\sim\frac{1}{\gamma}\ln\Lambda.$$For $d\ge3$, the integral is$$\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\right)^d\mu^{-2}\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\gamma}\,\Lambda}{\mu}\frac{x^{d-1}dx}{x^2+1}\sim\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\right)^d\mu^{-2}\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\gamma}\,\Lambda}{\mu}x^{d-3}dx=\frac{\gamma^{-1}}{d-2}\Lambda^{d-2}.$$While I use $f\sim g$ to mean $\lim_{\Lambda\to\infty}\frac{f}{g}=1$, Tong only requires the limit to be finite but nonzero.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Can you suggest some mathematical reference for asymptotic evaluation of integrals, as this one?

Comment: @GiancarloCreanza I don't have favourite texts, but will recommend search terms. For integrals of the form $\int_0^\Lambda k^{d-1}f(k)dk$ you really just need to check whether the integral converges as $\Lambda\to\infty$, and if it doesn't replace $f$ with a large-$k$ approximation thereof. There are other techniques you'll find if you research asymptotic expansion of integrals, but at least for these $k$-space integrals they're overkill. You'll find dimensional analysis an easier way to anticipate the result to within multiplicative constants Tong neglects.